# Data Insert Error in Mysqlserver

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, xampp

I want Data insert into mysql using PHP. I am writing script HTML, PHP and I create Mysql database. I don't understand data not send mysql server. Here is the HTML and PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
//Database Connection.

 mysql_select_db("learnarabic",$con);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO     article(ArticleDate,ArticleAuthor,ArticleSubject,ArticleSource,ArticleLevel,ArticleTitleEnglish,ArticleTitleArabic,ArticleFree,ArticleEnglish,ArticleTranslationEnglish,ArticleArabic,ArticleVowels,ArticleTransliteration,ArticleAudio) 
VALUES
('$_POST['ArticleDate']',
'$_POST['ArticleAuthor']',
'$_POST['ArticleSubject']',
'$_POST['ArticleSource']',
'$_POST['ArticleLevel']',
'$_POST['ArticleTitleEnglish']',
'$_POST['ArticleTitleArabic']',
'$_POST['ArticleFree']',
'$_POST['ArticleEnglish']',
'$_POST['ArticleTranslationEnglish']',
'$_POST['ArticleVowels']',
'$_POST['ArticleTransliteration']',
'$_POST['ArticleAudio']',
'$_POST['ArticleArabic']')";//Insert data into Mysql.


  mysql_query($sql,$con);

  mysql_close($con);//Connection Close.

 }  
 ?>
```

Here is the SQL Database code:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";



            --
-- Database: `learnarabic`
            --

            -- --------------------------------------------------------

            --
            -- Table structure for table `article`
            --

            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
              `articleid` int(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `ArticleDate` date NOT NULL,
              `ArticleAuthor` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
              `ArticleSubject` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
              `ArticleSource` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
              `ArticleLevel` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
              `ArticleTitleEnglish` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
              `ArticleTitleArabic` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
              `ArticleFree` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
              `ArticleEnglish` longtext NOT NULL,
              `ArticleTranslationEnglish` longtext NOT NULL,
              `ArticleArabic` longtext NOT NULL,
              `ArticleVowels` longtext NOT NULL,
              `ArticleTransliteration` longtext NOT NULL,
              `ArticleAudio` blob NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`articleid`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I need a solution.

Comment: wall of code questions dont go down to well [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you post your error ?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Post the relevant part,this is not drown people with code competition.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `$con` variable from the `mysql_query()` function eg `mysql_query($sql);` also add single quotes to any text inside `$_POST` like `$_POST['something']`